# Include server time in XMPP message

Tags: xmpp, openfire

Is it possible to include to XMPP message time when message was delivered to server?

Now I receive from OpenFire server messages like:

```
<message id="W45Ky-21" to="eee@jserv.ee" from="ppp@jserv.ee/dfg5465fd" type="chat"><body>test</body></message>
```

But I need know when message was sended (delivered to server) like:

```
<message id="W45Ky-21" to="eee@jserv.ee" from="ppp@jserv.ee/dfg5465fd" type="chat"><body>test</body><time>2012-10-12 10:00:52</time></message>
```

Comment: I need something similar, but settled on putting in the time manually while sending the message.

Comment: in that case, you get wrong message date if sender changes the device date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XMPP is a realtime protocol, so the message should be routed immediately with only some milliseconds delay. When a recipient is offline and the message gets stored offline and delivered later then the server stamps the message like described here:
[XEP-0203: Delayed Delivery](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0203.html)

If you want to stamp every outgoing message with a time you could use the created header from [XEP-0131: Stanza Headers and Internet Metadata](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0131.html) or define your own custom XMPP extension.

Comment: Can you please guide me how can i get server time in with every message?

Comment: as said above, a server stamps only offline messages with the time, because all other messages are realtime and don't require a timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But is there any way to add server time in every messages. As, Sometime, I'm not getting delay time in offline messages.